# Applicability of results about prime gaps

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I am interested in some general result about the gap between consecutive primes. This means that this result can be used in a proof of facts about all the primes: it is possible to use tables of gaps for "small" primes and apply this result for "big" primes. For example, R.C. Baker, G. Harman and J. Pintz in 2000 showed that the interval $[x-x^{0.525},x]$ contains prime numbers for all $x>x_0$. However, I haven't found any real estimation for $x_0$. Is there any resource where the value of $x_0$ was calculated? I am interested in integers $x$. A simple program shows that there is only one exception $x=126$ if $x\leq 10^7$.

Maybe there are some other results with calculated $x_0$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost all strong results of this type do not have an explicit value for $x_0$. Dusart has explicit values which do not depend on RH but do rely on knowledge of zeta zeroes.  Also, the explicit bounds of Dusart are asymptotically weaker.  Gerhard "But They Involve Explicit Numerics" Paseman, 2017.01.03.

Comment: Thank you. I found both [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0442.pdf) and [published](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-016-9839-4) versions of Dusart's result. You wrote that the result relies on knowledge of zeta zeroes. Did you mean calculations of first zeroes on computers?

Comment: For the actual theory (of which I am a poor guide) I refer you to the classic article of Rosser and Schonfeld which undoubtedly is referenced by Dusart. (I reference R and S in my preprint 1311.5944.) They tell you how they use the zeros, and I imagine Dusart has made little change to that part of the theory.  Gerhard "But Oh What He Does" Paseman, 2017.01.03.